# Retrieve Calendar Entry TimeZone

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, gdata-api, gdata

I am developing an app that connects to Google Calendar in Java. So far I've managed to retrieve all the data I wanted, I realized yesterday that Google now allows to define events with different timezones than the calendar's.

Is there a way of getting an event timezone?

Thanks in advance.

Mikywan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They gave this answer in Google Calendar Api's forum:

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/community/forum.html?place=topic%2Fgoogle-calendar-help-dataapi%2FpYf-9CIeZnw%2Fdiscussion